# Devolver el valor del input cuando le doy click al segundo boton

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objeto

Hola muchachos lo que pasa es que tengo que encriptar un texto el cual está en un input, el primer botón lo encripta mediante una función que hice y en el segundo botón volver el texto a la normalidad, la primera parte ya la tengo pero a la hora de volver a traer el texto original no se como volver a descriptarlo y dejarlo en la caja de texto, no se si alguien me pueda ayudar, debe ser un error muy simple, pero la verdad no lo encuentro, gracias por la ayuda

```js
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener('click', () => {

    function encriptar() {
        let str = '';
        let ref = 'abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz';
        var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            str += ref.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * ref.length));
            var resultado = document.getElementById('input').value = str;
            console.log(resultado)
            console.log(input)
        }
    }


    encriptar()

})

document.getElementById('btn2').addEventListener('click', () => {
    function desencriptar() {
        var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
        console.log(input)
    }
    desencriptar()
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>criptograma</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="input">
    <button id="btn1">Encriptar</button>
    <button id="btn2">Descepcritar</button>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, me temo que para la forma en la que modificas las cadenas no es posible devolverlas a su estado anterior debido a que empleas una número aleatorio en `ref.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * ref.length));`, aunque se puede pensar en una alternativa si cambias la función de encriptar.

Comment: Hola the-breaker, no se algún concejo, para poder hacer lo que necesito, un boton que me encripte y el otro que me lo devuelva a su estado original, gracias.

Comment: Puedes emplear codigo cesar, es un metodo de cifrado  no de encrptacion pero resuelve el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Analizando tu código no estás cifrando nada en realidad, símplemente estás reemplazando el texto original por una cadena generada aleatoreamente.

En caso de que requieras un método de cifrado, te propongo el siguiente código que implementa el cifrado césar.

```js
let claveCesar;
let listaLetras = 'abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz';

// Para calcular el módulo adecuadamente
function mod(n, m) {
  return ((n % m) + m) % m;
}

function encriptar(cadenaInicial) {
  // Utilizando cifrado cesar
  // Calculamos un número aleatorio en el rango de 
  // las letras del español
  let cadenaNueva = '';
  // Para mayor facilidad convertimos toda la cadena en minúscula
  cadenaInicial = cadenaInicial.toLowerCase();
  claveCesar = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26);
  claveCesar = 1

  for (let i = 0; i < cadenaInicial.length; i++) {
    cadenaNueva += listaLetras[mod((listaLetras.indexOf(cadenaInicial[i]) + claveCesar), 27)];
  }

  console.log(cadenaNueva);
  return cadenaNueva;
}

function desencriptar(cadenaInicial) {
  // Revisamos si previamente se ha establecido una valor como llave para el cifrado
  let cadenaDescifrada = '';
  if (claveCesar) {
    for (let i = 0; i < cadenaInicial.length; i++) {
      cadenaDescifrada += listaLetras[mod((listaLetras.indexOf(cadenaInicial[i]) - claveCesar), 27)];
    }
  }
  console.log(cadenaDescifrada);
  return cadenaDescifrada;
}

// Encriptar
document.getElementById('btn1')
  .addEventListener('click', function () {
    let mensaje = document.getElementById('input').value;
    document.getElementById('input').value = encriptar(mensaje);
  });

// Desencriptar
document.getElementById('btn2')
  .addEventListener('click', function () {
    let mensaje = document.getElementById('input').value;
    document.getElementById('input').value = desencriptar(mensaje);
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>criptograma</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="text" id="input" />
    <button id="btn1">Encriptar</button>
    <button id="btn2">Descepcritar</button>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: buena respuesta, aunque creo que la linea `claveCesar = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26);` no es necesaria.

Comment: Esa línea permite generar una llave aleatoria, si se quiere se puede dejar un número fijo, pero un número aleatorio es igualmente válido.

Comment: ok, entiendo, se puede comentar una para emplear otra.